# Looking for a good way to render responsive image srcSet in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, responsive-images

on a create-react-app project we have some bitmap local images to display, e.g.

```
src/images/logo.png
src/images/logo@2x.png
src/images/logo@3x.png
```

anyone know of any good ways to simplify making these responsive? i.e. to populate the srcset like this https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/

in react-native they have a nice way of handling 1x, 2x, 3x etc and it all works with this:

```
<Image source={require("../images/logo.png")} />
```

wondering what a nice solution for this looks like on CRA.